# Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem proof question

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, self-learning, cauchy-sequences

Since $[a_n,b_n] \subset [x,y] \forall n$, we know that  $Q = \{a_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$is bounded

Let $t= \sup Q$ (which will be the accumulation point)

Let $P$ be any neighborhood of $t$, so that there is some $\epsilon>0$ where $(t- \epsilon, t+ \epsilon) \subset P$

$t-\epsilon $ is not an upper bound for $Q$ since $t=\sup Q$

Therefore there is a positive integer n where $t- \epsilon < a_n \le a_m \le t$

If $m>n$, then $t- \epsilon <a_n \le a_m \le t$

Each $[a_m,b_m]$ contains infinitely many points of $S$ so the proof would be done if we found m such that $t - \epsilon < a_m < b_m < t+ \epsilon$

We know that $t- \epsilon <a_m \le t$ for $m \ge n$, so we must choose m large enough so that $m \ge n$ and $2^{-m}(y-x) < \epsilon$ which is the length of $[a_m, b_m]$

So choose $m \ge n$ such that $t- \epsilon < a_m \le t \le b_m = a_m -(a_m - b_m) = a_m - 2^{-m}(y-x)$

Therefore $P$ contains $[a_m,b_m]$ or an infinite amount of members of $S$ and $t$ is an accumulation point of $S$.

**The only part that I don't understand is how exactly we picked $Q$ to be $a_n$ and not $b_n$.**

Comment: You could, given you change upper to lower and the direction of inequalities.

Comment: Did I doze off and miss the beginning? What is S and what are you trying to prove?

Comment: "The only part that I don't understand ...."   You are way ahead of the rest of us since, until you edit the question, we have no idea what you are trying to do here.